# Custom dialog getview returns null

Tags: android

I am new to android and i tried learning custom dialogs.

From what i understood from the docs:

I created a `iMusicDialog` class which extends `DialogFragment`, this is what my code looks like.

`iMusicDialog.java`

```
public class iMusicDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.imusicplaydialog,null);
        builder.setView(v);
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Now i have an activity in which i want to show it.This is what i did:

`Myactivity.java`

```
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMusicDialog=new iMusicDialog();
        View v=mMusicDialog.getView();
        Log.e("TAG_POSN","outside");


        if(v!=null) {
            playpause=v.findViewById(R.id.dialogControl);
            playpause.setOnClickListener(this);
            seekBar=v.findViewById(R.id.dialogSeekbar);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
            Log.e("TAG_POSN","inside");
            mSongDisplay=v.findViewById(R.id.dialogTextview);
            mImage=v.findViewById(R.id.dialogThumnbnail);
        }
        seekBar.setMax(100);
        intent=getIntent();
        if (intent == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Audio playback Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        mMusicDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"some text");
    }
```

Logcat:

```
12-24 01:49:57.288 30063-30063/? E/TAG_POSN: outside
12-24 01:49:57.336 30063-30063/? E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
12-24 01:49:57.336 30063-30063/? E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
12-24 01:49:57.336 30063-30063/? E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
12-24 01:49:57.336 30063-30063/? E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
12-24 01:49:57.580 30063-30063/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.tilak.imusicplay, PID: 30063
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setMax(int)' on a null object
```

As the log show i am not getting the view from the `iMusicDialog` class.

How do i get it? Am i doing it right?

Update:

```
public class iMusicDialogActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener ,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,OnAudioFocusChangeListener{
    private static final String TAG_LOG = "Debug";
    private Intent intent=null;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private Song song;
    private ToggleButton playpause;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private boolean paused=false;
    private static final int OSVERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private TextView mSongDisplay;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private iMusicDialog mMusicDialog;
```

Update 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/dialogParent1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialogParent2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contains_song_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/dialogThumnbnail"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/dialogTextview"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/dialogControl"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play_pause_small"
            android:textOn="" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/dialogSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout file just incase

Comment: In youre code you do not show where seekBar variable is defined, could you show where you created it?

Comment: @Aaron please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is saying that

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setMax(int)' on a null object
```

This means that you called setMax(int) on a null SeekBar.

Comment: Try casting, but with the view variable, not with just the class like in another answer I read on here.

seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogSeekBar); 

See if that gets you anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
seekbar.setMax(100)
```

With:

```
seekBar.setMax(100)
```

You forgot to capitalize the B in seekBar.

Comment: simple `findviewid` inside activity will look inside the current layout of the activity? this doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Where do you exactly have dialogSeekBar defined? Where ever that is is where you need to find that view by it's id.

Comment: The reason you are getting null in the first place is because the view you originally passed in does not contain dialogSeekBar.

Comment: its inside a seperate class

Comment: i know that , why am i getting it, i am asking that and how to solve it

Comment: I just told you how you got it. The view you pass in originally was v. v was the iMusicDialog view which obviously didn't contain the dialogSeekBar.

Comment: please take a look at the uodated question

Comment: Solving it is as simple as referring the view to the seekBar variable and calling that view then finding the Id of that view in it's layout file. Post the layout file code that has the seekBar in it.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tilak.imusicplay/com.example.tilak.imusicplay.iMusicDialogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Dialog.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: I got it now check my answer

Comment: that was typo, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161872/discussion-between-aaron-and-botjr).

Comment: Oh woops didn't mean to send that last message

Comment: but alright. Try one more thing then I am out of ideas:seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogSeekBar);

Answer (score 0):

Try to get dialog views like this

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) mMusicDialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.dialogSeekbar);
```

Comment: this is not working, this straight up wont show the findviewbyid suggestion on it